# yield keyword instead of return within a function called through map()

Tags: python, function, dictionary, return, yield

I am using map() to apply the function x to a list of elements. 
map() returns an iterator yielding the results. However, the function X already yield the value, not return. I need to use yield only one time.

```py
def x(line):
    columns = line.strip().split('\t')
    yield columns

values = [ 'a\tb\tc\td\n',
           'g\tc\tq\tm\n',
           's\tp\to\td\n'
         ]
iters = map(x, values)

for i in iters:
  print(next(i))
```

it output

```py
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
['g', 'c', 'q', 'm']
['s', 'p', 'o', 'd']
```

The code runs and I do not have any error. However, I think that this is an overdoing since I am 'yielding' the output two times.

I am curious to know if instead I should change function x with the return keyword.

Comment: this doesn't make any sense. can you please elaborate on exactly what you are trying to accomplish with a [mcve]

Comment: the function passed to `map` operates on a single object of the list, and not the list itself.

Comment: Does `x` just have a single `yield` statement? i.e. it will always return a generator that has a single element to iterate over?

Answer (score 0):

`Map` creates a generator itself without the need for `yield` in the function definition.

Using `return` will suffice.

Comment: `map` does not create a generator, it returns a `map` object, which is an iterator. In any case, the OP seems to already understand this, since they've stated that themselves

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga oops, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is similar to this

```
values = [5 , 9]
iters = map(range, values)
```

when you apply `x` on `values` your are creating a list `(actually a generator because map return a generator in 3.x)` of `generators`.

```
for it in iters:
    for value in it:
        # do somthing
```